# Symfony association with specific conditions

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have a entity `Item` and another one is `ItemReferral`

`Item` is associated as `oneToMany` with `ItemReferral`

`ItemReferral` table has `item_id` and `user_id` fields

It's working already.

Now when I fetch items then I get all `ItemReferrals` of items but I want to control associated `ItemReferral`s to specific `user_id`.

For example:

`Item` with id 10 has many `ItemReferral`s with (`item_id` 10, `user_id` 1, `item_id` 10 `user_id` 2) but in association result I want to get `ItemReferral` of `user_id` 1 for each item, how to achieve this ?

Comment: Use repositories and pass your specific user_id as an argument. build your query with that.

Comment: Use doctrine filters like described here: http://blog.michaelperrin.fr/2014/12/05/doctrine-filters/